# echo json_encode response is not working with mail function

Tags: php, json, curl

I have used `curl` for generated the report and send mail to user.

here is my code

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
$ret = json_decode($ret, true);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($ret);
```

here i am using my mail function and return json encode response but nothing get in response.
if i comment  `send_report_to_user` function then i am able to get response

```
$to="test@gmail.com";
$name="Test";
$report_links='MYREPORT LINKS';
send_report_to_user($to,$name,$report_links);

echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','message'=>"Report has been generated successfully. Please check your mail to view reports."));
die;

function send_report_to_user($to,$name,$report_links)
{
    $mailheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mailheaders .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $mailheaders .= "From: Mcs <do_not_reply@mcs.com>";
    $subject = "Your Report is Ready";
    $body_message='<p>Your Report is now ready to be viewed here:</p>
                   <p><a href="'.$report_links.'" target="_blank">Click Here to view report</a></p>
                   <p>&nbsp;</p>';
    mail($to,$subject,$body_message,$mailheaders);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: any error or exception you are getting?

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR no code is working fine only response is not get. also mail is receive

Comment: check what you are getting here `mail($to,$subject,$body_message,$mailheaders);`

Comment: @hassan but function call above the die

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR mail is working fine

Comment: Can you do `print_r($ret)` after `$ret = curl_exec($ch);` and check what is it showing?. Also do `json_last_error()` after `json_decode()`, that would show any json_decode errors, if there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have issue with your `send_report_to_user` function. You are using variable `$mailheaders` but have not defined it. Try defining the variable before using it and it may work for you.

Please try with below code

```
function send_report_to_user($to,$name,$report_links)
{
    $mailheaders = '';
    $mailheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mailheaders .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $mailheaders .= "From: Mcs <do_not_reply@mcs.com>";
    $subject = "Your Report is Ready";
    $body_message='<p>Your Report is now ready to be viewed here:</p>
                   <p><a href="'.$report_links.'" target="_blank">Click Here to view report</a></p>
                   <p>&nbsp;</p>';
    mail($to,$subject,$body_message,$mailheaders);
    return true;
}
```